# Check if radio button is checked and update another field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with two radio buttons 'phone me' and 'collect keys'. In order for the user to only select one of the two options, the input name are the same for both. If the user selects the first radio button where the value is equal to yes, then update the below database field:

```
UPDATE survey_bookings_mainsite SET appointment_phone = 'Yes' WHERE ref = $ref
```

else if the second radio button where the value is equal to no, then update the below database field:

```
UPDATE survey_bookings_mainsite SET appointment_keys = 'Yes' WHERE ref = $ref
```

**Issue:** 
The second query returns 'No' in the `appointment_phone` field and displays NULL in the `appointment_keys` field. What is supposed to happen is the `appointment_phone` field to display 'No' and the `appointment_keys` field to also display 'Yes'. I have tried to in the second IF-Statement to re-assign `$appointment_phone` to equal to look like this:

```
$appointment_phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['appointment_keys']);
```

but that doesn't work.

```
include("config/cn.php");
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    // Use array_map to secure all POST values:
    $_POST = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);
    $ref                        = $_POST['ref'];
    $property_number            = $_POST['property_number'];
    $property_address1          = $_POST['property_address1'];
    $property_address2          = $_POST['property_address2'];
    $property_town              = $_POST['property_town'];
    $property_postcode          = $_POST['property_postcode'];
    $appointment_phone          = $_POST['appointment_phone'];
    $appointment_contact_number = $_POST['appointment_contact_number'];
    $appointment_keys           = $_POST['appointment_keys'];

    if($_POST['appointment_phone'] == 'Yes'){
        $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE survey_bookings_mainsite SET appointment_phone = 'Yes' WHERE ref = $ref");
    }
    if ($_POST['appointment_phone'] == 'No'){
        $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE survey_bookings_mainsite SET appointment_keys = 'Yes' WHERE ref = $ref");
    }

    $collect_number       = $_POST['collect_number'];
    $collect_postcode     = $_POST['collect_postcode'];
    $collect_address1     = $_POST['collect_address1'];
    $collect_address2     = $_POST['collect_address2'];
    $collect_town         = $_POST['collect_town'];
    $collect_phone        = $_POST['collect_phone'];
    $report_name          = $_POST['report_name'];
    $report_number        = $_POST['report_number'];
    $report_address1      = $_POST['report_address1'];
    $report_address2      = $_POST['report_address2'];
    $report_town          = $_POST['report_town'];
    $report_postcode      = $_POST['report_postcode'];
    $report_phone         = $_POST['report_phone'];
    $report_email         = $_POST['report_email'];
    $special_instructions = $_POST['special_instructions'];

    $enter_sql = "INSERT INTO survey_bookings_mainsite (ref,property_number,property_address1,property_address2,property_town,property_postcode,appointment_phone,appointment_contact_number,collect_number,
                                       collect_address1,collect_address2,collect_town,collect_postcode,collect_phone,report_name,report_number,report_address1,report_address2,report_town,
                                       report_postcode,report_phone,report_email,special_instructions)
                                       VALUES(\"$ref\",\"$property_number\",\"$property_address1\",\"$property_address2\",\"$property_town\",
                                       \"$property_postcode\",\"$appointment_phone\",\"$appointment_contact_number\",\"$collect_number\",\"$collect_address1\",\"$collect_address2\",\"$collect_town\",\"$collect_postcode\",
                                       \"$collect_phone\",\"$report_name\",\"$report_number\",\"$report_address1\",\"$report_address2\",\"$report_town\",\"$report_postcode\",\"$report_phone\",\"$report_email\",\"$special_instructions\")";                                   

    $enter_query = mysql_query($enter_sql);
    header('Location: /thankyou.php');  
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Made some changes to your code like `array_map()` ( php.net/array_map ) to improve readability and maintainability :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your two if-statements will never run both, one will work on `yes` and one will work on `no`. You have to combine them into 1 query:

```
$query = "UPDATE survey_bookings_mainsite SET 
             appointment_phone = '".($_POST['appointment_phone']=='Yes' ? 'Yes' : 'No')."' ,
             appointment_keys  = '".($_POST['appointment_phone']=='No'  ? 'Yes' : 'No')."'
          WHERE ref = $ref LIMIT 1";
$sql = mysql_query($query);
```

I took the liberty of adding `LIMIT 1`, if you only have to update 1 line, this will increase speed significantly when there is more load :)

The code in the query is short if/else, or ternairy. The following does exactly the same

```
if( $var === true ){ echo 'yes';}
else{                echo 'No';}

echo $var ===true ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

---

You method could actually work (though I strongly recommend you **don't** do the following!):

```
// Same code, simplefied for example:
if($_POST['appointment_phone'] == 'Yes'){
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET appointment_phone = 'Yes',appointment_keys='No'";
}
if ($_POST['appointment_phone'] == 'No'){
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET appointment_phone = 'No',appointment_keys='Yes'";
}
```

You dont want this because now you have two queries doing almost the exact same thing. What if you want to switch to 1/0 instead of yes/no? You would have to switch two queries (twice the room for error). 
Just imagine what would happen if you have 10 inputs like this.

Comment: Would you kindly explain what your code is doing? :S

Comment: Made an edit the same time you asked. I expanded my answer even more now

Comment: right, i understand. So combining both IF-Statements into one, i would do something like if($_POST['appointment_phone']) {} and then put the update statement between the brackets?

Comment: You replace those two if's (completely) with that code. The ifstatements have moved into the query (see extra info I added)

Comment: ok, so i have completely replaced the two IFs with the code and placed it before my insert query. When i submit my form, i just get a blank page.

Comment: `White page of death`, look it up ;)

Comment: so i no longer have a white page, thank goodness. However, my database is still just saying no in the appointment_phone field instead of both appointment_phone and appointment_keys

Comment: With the information I gave you, you should be able to fix it yourself. I don't have the time (or knowledge of your system) to completely fix it :)